# Prove that $ \sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1&2&3&4&5 \\ 2&3&4&1&5 \end{array} \right) \neq s_1 \circ s_2 \circ \ldots \circ s_k $

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Prove that we can't write permutation $ \sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 \end{array} \right) $ as $s_1 \circ s_2 \circ \ldots \circ s_k $ where $s_1, s_2 , \ldots, s_k \in \left\{ \sigma_1= \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 \end{array} \right), \sigma_2 = \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 3 \end{array} \right)  \right\} $.

We have

$ \sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 \end{array} \right) = (1234)
\\ \sigma_1 = \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 \end{array} \right) = (123)
\\ \sigma_2 =  \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 3 \end{array} \right) = (345) $

$ \mathrm{ord}( \sigma ) = 4 \\ \mathrm{ord} (\sigma_1) = 3 \\ \mathrm{ord}( \sigma_2) = 3$

Then I was thinking about $\mathrm{ord}(s_1 \circ \ldots \circ s_k)$ and maybe I should prove that $\mathrm{ord}(s_1 \circ \ldots \circ s_k) \neq 4 = \mathrm{ord}(\sigma)$ ?

But I have no idea how to prove it. Furthermore, I'm not sure, is it possible? Maybe is another way to do this task? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint/Spoiler: Have you checked the parities of all the permutations here?

Comment: So $\sigma$ is odd. Because $\sigma_1$ is even and $\sigma_2$ is odd then $s_1 \circ \ldots \circ s_k$ may be even or odd.

Comment: Hmm. $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are both 3-cycles, so they are conjugates. Hence they have the same parity...

Comment: Sorry, of course I'm wrong. $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are even so $s_1 \circ \ldots \circ s_k$ is even. But $\sigma$ is odd. Now is all right?

Comment: Correct, @Tomek. Well done! All those products belong to the subgroup $A_5$, but $\sigma$ does not.